# ConsoleLogger writing logs out of order in aws lambda with 3.1

Tags: aws-lambda, .net-core-3.1

We have an AWS lambda with .net core 3.1, we use dependency injection to add some services, one of those services is a ConsoleLogger, we inject the logger like this:

```
private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    this.Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
    services.AddOptions();
    services.AddLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddConsole((x) =>
        {
            x.DisableColors = true;
            x.Format = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLoggerFormat.Systemd;
        });
    });
    
    // more services
}
```

Then in the function we use the logger like this:

```
[LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
public async Task Handle(ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
{
    var logger = this.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILogger<MyClass>>();

    string startTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    logger.LogInformation($"Start Time stamp:{startTime}|AwsRequestId:{lambdaContext.AwsRequestId}");
    
    // more work
    logger.LogInformation("processing x");
    // more work
    string endTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    logger.LogInformation($"End Time stamp:{endTime}|AwsRequestId:{lambdaContext.AwsRequestId}");
}
```

The problem is that in cloudwatch the logs are out of order
[image]

Even the report of the cost is before my entry.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConsoleLogger` buffers messages in an internal queue, so they're probably getting delayed there, and it's nothing to do with CloudWatch. Amazon's own CloudWatch logging library does the same thing, and they note in their own documentation that it can be a problem for Lambdas: https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/#aws-lambda

Their recommended solution is to use [Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore) which doesn't do any buffering.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe you can do this with CloudWatch.  CloudWatch guarantees delivery, not timely delivery.  You could set up a Dynamo or ElasticSearch database and write your log messages to the database with a timestamp.  On retrieval you can sort by the timestamp.  This also gives you more control over filtering the messages than is possible with CloudWatch.